# Erro na barra final com mod_rewrite e mod_jk

Tags: apache, tomcat, jsf-2.2, url-rewrite

Tenho a seguinte estrutura em meu servidor.

- Apache HTTPD (porta 80)
- Tomcat (porta 8080)

Utilizei o `mod_jk` para fazer a conexão entre o apache e o tomcat e isso está funcionando perfeitamente.

Criei um subdomínio para apontar para uma aplicação que está no tomcat. E fiz a seguinte configuração de VirtualHost.

```apache
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.cardapio.dreamt.com.br
    ServerAlias cardapio.dreamt.com.br
    JkMount /cardapio/* worker1
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) /cardapio/$1 [L,PT]
</VirtualHost>
```

Porém ,e deparei com dois problemas:

1. Ao acessar **cardapio.dreamt.com.br/dreamtech/** (com a barra no final) a aplicação é executada sem nenhuma problema. E ao acessar **cardapio.dreamt.com.br/dreamtech** (sem a barra final) sou redirecionado para uma URL inválida **cardapio.dreamt.com.br/cardapio/dreamtech/**.
2. Ao acessar cardapio.dreamt.com.br/ minha aplicação não funciona pois ela está tentando buscar os JS e CSS de **cardapio.dreamt.com.br/*cardapio*/xxx.js** (por exemplo). E eu não consigo alterar pois esses imports são feitos automaticamente pelo JSF.

Como resolver esses problemas?

Answer (score 1):

A seguinte regra de reescrita acrescenta uma barra ao final especificamente no caso de acesso ao caminho `/dreamtech`:

```apache
RewriteRule ^(dreamtech)$ $1/ [R]
```

Tente colocar da seguinte forma:

```apache
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.cardapio.dreamt.com.br
    ServerAlias cardapio.dreamt.com.br
    JkMount /cardapio/* worker1
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(dreamtech)$ $1/ [R]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) /cardapio/$1 [L,PT]
</VirtualHost>
```

O guia da própria Apache dá umas dicas sobre essa questão da barra e recomenda esse tipo de abordagem. [Veja aqui](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).

Anteriormente, eu havia feito uma tentativa usando a condição de reescrita genérica verificando se a URL dizia respeito a um arquivo, mas isso não funcionaria mesmo, já que você está fazendo conexão com um Tomcat.

Você pode fazer alguns testes do módulo de reescrita [aqui](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/) ou [aqui](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

Comment: Mesmo com essa mudança não funcinou. Sem a barra fui redirecionando para http://cardapio.dreamt.com.br//cardapio//cardapio//cardapio//cardapio//cardapio//cardapio//cardapio//cardapio//cardapio//cardapio//dreamtech/

Comment: @gtonioli Reformulei a resposta. Por favor, faça um teste novamente.

Comment: Não funcionou utluiz. Vou fazer alguns nos sites que você indicou.